# О чём говорит предупреждение о выравнивании данных?

Tags: c++, память, gcc, выравнивание

При компиляции такого кода для ARM

```
char* c = 0;
int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(c);
```

GCC выводит предупреждение

> cast from ‘char*’ to ‘int*’ increases required alignment of target type

Какими последствиями чревато подобное применение **reinterpret_cast** для типов с разными требованиями по выравниванию? Почему такое предупреждение возникает не на всех платформах? О чём вообще это, нужно ли как-то исправлять?

https://godbolt.org/g/VGDK3w

По ссылке выше вы увидете попытку компиляции такого кода для процессоров x86_64 и ARM. Несмотря на одинаковые флаги компилятора, результат получился разным.

Comment: `int` - это signed. `char` - это unsigned. И.е. `int` может иметь отрицательную знаковую часть. Это предупреждение, чтобы программист помнил это.

Comment: Это чревато исключением (на уровне аппаратуры -- exception) при доступу по указателю `p` (впрочем, зависит от архитектуры). Вообще это означает, что данные к которым вы обращаетесь могут находится по адресу не кратном размеру адресуемого элемента данных

Comment: @MrBin, знаковый char приводит к аналогичному предупреждению - https://godbolt.org/g/kaEvR5

Comment: Ну, я обозначил самою очевидную вещь. Есть ещё переполнение и смеси всего. И это без особенностей платформ.

Comment: @MrBin, вы не правы. Речь о выравнивании данных в памяти

Comment: @avp, тогда остаётся только переполнение. А так 8 бит одного типа и 8 бит другого будет работать одинаково. Но только если одинаковое их количество)

Comment: @MrBin, вот эти слова `increases required alignment of target type` в тексте вопроса вы видели?

Comment: @avp, перечитайте лучше мой последний комментарий. Тем более уже дан развернутый ответ.

Comment: Это UB, но я не возьмусь сейчас выискивать все релевантные цитаты из стандарта. Но начать можно со strict aliasing. P.S. avp всё правильно говорит.

Comment: @MrBin, и где в сообщении компилятора вы увидели что-то о переполнении?

Comment: Не совсем понятно замечание про "результат получился разным". Вас удивляет, что машинный код для двух разных процессоров отличается?

Comment: @AnT, нуу... для ARM там вообще никакого кода не получилось.

Comment: @mymedia: Ну так вы запросили прерывание генерации кода для нестандартного диагностического сообщения. Нестандартные диагностические сообщения они такие - сегодня есть, завтра нет, в одном месте есть, в другом нет...

Comment: @avp, я спорить не собираюсь. Но. Я привет простой пример, когда можно безвозмездно приводить типы (Примерах хорошего приведения). Логично можно было подумать, что приведение char к большему разряду int будет примером плохого приведения.  Указатель на 8 к указателю на (16-32-64) и вуаля. UB. Так что советую ещё раз перечитать) А вы придираетесь к слову переполнение.

Comment: @MrBin: "`char` - это unsigned". Почему вы решили, что это именно так?

Comment: @MrBin,о чем вы вообще говорите? Я о конкретном вопросе автора -- `Какими последствиями чревато подобное применение reinterpret_cast для типов с разными требованиями по выравниванию?`. Если говорить о конкретном коде в тексте вопроса, то независимо от предупреждения ничего плохого ни в ARM, ни на X86 не произойдет, поскольку обращения к памяти  по указателям в нем нет

Comment: С каких пор `char` стал `unsigned`?

Comment: @NewView, строго говоря, знаковость char зависит от реализации. Вот в GCC это даже можно настроить - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518559/5000805

Comment: Да GCC/clang чего угодно настроить можно, согласен :) а вот реализация где char по умолчанию unsigned? не разу не сталкивался с таким.

Answer (score 13):

Поведение `reinterpret_cast` в этом случае зависит от платформы. Начиная с С++11 поведение такого преобразования определяется как

```
int* p = static_cast<int *>(static_cast<void *>(c));
```

и результат будет зависеть от поведения внешнего `static_cast`. Поведение `static_cast` из `void *` в объектный указательный тип является неспецифицированным, если исходный `void *` адрес не удовлетворяет требованиям выравнивания целевого типа.

- На одной платформе приведение типа от указателя с более расслабленными требованиями выравнивания к указателю с более строгими требованиями выравнивания может привести к потере оригинального адресного значения, т.е. компилятор и/или аппаратура насильно выравняют указатель.
- На другой платформе адресное значение указателя сохранится, но при попытке доступа через невыровненный указатель программа будет аварийно остановлена.
- На третьей платформе адресное значение указателя сохранится, но при доступе через невыровненный указатель такой доступ будет производиться успешно, но менее эффективно.
- На четвертой платформе не будет вообще никаких негативных последствий.

Предупреждение о выравнивании данных может либо говорить том, что подобные проблемы могут иметь место на вашей платформе, либо просто являться педантичным "предупреждением портабельности", т.е. говорить том, ваш код может вести себя по-другому на других платформах.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, reinterpret_cast не вызывает каких-либо преобразований времени выполнения, это чисто для компилятора. А вот второй случай уже интереснее, как бы такое падение воспроизвести?

Comment: @mymedia: В спецификации `reinterpret_cast` не сказано, что он "не вызывает каких-либо преобразований времени выполнения, это чисто для компилятора". Как раз наоборот, там сказано, что круговое преобразование `T* -> U* -> T*` не гарантирует сохранения исходного значения указателя, если тип `U` имеет более строгие требования выравнивания. Это именно задел на возможность потери значения в таких ситуациях. А "преобразования" могут быть жестко заложены в аппаратуру.

Comment: @mymedia: Падения во втором случае будут воспроизводиться на платформах с жесткими требованиями выравнивания, типа Solaris. При доступе сразу получите Bus Error.

Comment: @mymedia, найдите код, который компилятор векторизует (это не так сложно, можно сумму простую сделать и поизучать код). Потом переделайте его так, чтобы получился массив с невыровненными int. Таким образом получите исключение даже на x86.

Comment: Доступ по невыровненному указателю называется "unaligned access". Из широко распространённых процессоров невозможностью unaligned access страдали ARM7, ARM9 - при попытке чтения 32-битного значения по адресу, некратному четырём, случался exception. Более новые ARM'ы (Cortex -A, -M, -R) в этом случае корректно читают значение (правда, при этом производится пара обращений к памяти вместо одного)

Comment: Так и не понял, нужно ли исправлять такое предупреждение или можно его проигнорировать.