# __attribute__((__packed__))

Tags: c++, c, атрибуты

Не совсем понимаю, что происходит при упаковке, например, структур.

Допустим:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s
{
    int i;
    char c;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));

int main()
{
    struct s arr[2];

    printf("sizeof(s): %Iu\n", sizeof(struct s));
    printf("sizeof(arr): %Iu\n", sizeof(arr));

    printf("%p\n", &(arr[1].i));

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
sizeof(s): 5
sizeof(arr): 10
0060FEFB
```

Получается, что начиная `arr[1]` поле `i` имеет неверное выравнивание, потому что адрес `0060FEFB` не кратен `sizeof(int)`. А согласно стандарту, работа с невыровненными данными - это неопределенное поведение. Например, если мы обратимся такому к полю `i` через указатель (`->`, `*`), то получим неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Он остаётся без изменений. Т.е. char дополняется до размера sizeof(int), а int уже имеет такой размер, поэтому его просто не нужно выравнивать.

Comment: А если i c поменять местами, то в неупакованой структуре с будет иметь адрес +0, и будет дополнен, а i будет иметь адрес +4. Если не менять - то же самое, один элемент будет иметь адрес +0, а другой +4 из-за выравнивания.

Comment: @nick_n_a, char никуда не дополняется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Доступ к невыровненым данным формально приводит к неопределенному поведению. Однако С/С++ реализации могут предоставлять такой доступ в качестве расширения. При этом реализации делятся на несколько типов по отношению к выравниванию.

1. Выравнивание требуется на уровне аппаратуры. Реализация не предпринимает никаких мер для обхода требований аппаратуры. Попытка доступа к невыровненным данным приводит к аварийному завершению программы.
2. Выравнивание требуется на уровне аппаратуры. Реализация выполняет безопасный (по частям) доступ к потенциально невыровненным данным. Доступ к потенциально невыровненным данным возможен, но существенно менее производителен.
3. Выравнивание не требуется на уровне аппаратуры. Реализации не надо ни о чем беспокоиться. Доступ к потенциально невыровненным данным возможен, но обычно несколько менее эффективен.

Вы скорее всего имеете дело с реализацией типа 3.

См. также [О чём говорит предупреждение о выравнивании данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/%D0%9E-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: А разве сам Стандарт не говорит о том, что работа с невыровненными данными, - это неопределенное поведение на уровне языка, независимо от того, позволяет ли целевая платформа работать с такими данными или нет?

Comment: Стандарт не может знать на какой ЦП и OS вы работаете.

Comment: @nick_n_a, вот именно. Поэтому в стандарте говорится, что нельзя работать с неверно выровненными данными. Конкретно, оператор `*` имеет неопределенное поведение, если указатель указывает данные, выравнивание которых не соответствует требованиям целевого типа.

Comment: @MGNeo, это что за стандарт такой?

Comment: C99: 6.5.3.2 Адрес и операция разыменования
Если указателю было присвоено недопустимое значение, поведение унарного оператора * не определено.

87) Среди недопустимых значений для разыменования оператора унарным оператором *: пустой указатель; ненадлежащим образом выровненный адрес для типа указываемого объекта; адрес объекта по окончании его использования

Comment: @MGNeo Стандарт говорит, что объекты должны создаваться в памяти, которая *корректно выровнена* ("properly aligned"). Что именно означает это "корректно" и где начинается "некорректно" - определяется реализацией.

Comment: Рассмотрим мой пример. Если структуру упаковать, и сделать массив из >= двух элементов, то начиная со второго элемента массива поле `int i` окажется неверно выровнено, потому что размер упакованной структуры = 5, а размер массива из двух элементов = 10. Может, я просто это неверно понимаю?

Comment: @AnT, само выравнивание (количественно) определяется реализацией, а вот наличие корректного выравнивания стандартом требуется. Т.е. если `alignof(int) == 4`,  а размещён он чёрти где, то это нарушение стандарта.

Comment: @AnT, в моем примере поле `i` второго элемента массива, судя по всему, будет валяться по адресу, не кратному `sizeof(int)`. Как это может быть корректным?

Comment: @MGNeo, в стандарте нет `__attribute__((__packed__))`, поэтому использование таких вещей на свой страх и риск. Возможно, GCC как-то по особому с такими типами работает и не даст нарваться на неприятности на платформах, где они возможны, а возможно — нет.

Comment: @MGNeo, обсуждать поведение кода с нестандартным `__attribute__((__packed__))` в рамках стандарта довольно бессмысленно... говоря `packed` программист сам берёт на себя работу по выравниванию для сборки под целевую архитектуру.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @MGNeo AnT имеет в виду, что в стандарте не сказано, что `alignof` возвращает "минимальное необходимое" выравнивание. Он запросто может возвращать "оптимальное" выраванивание.

Comment: win98 при невыравняном обращении при записи двойного слова с выходом за пределы страницы 4К - падал в креш (синий экран). На современных - давно не проверял.

Comment: @AnT, в приведенной вами ссылке рассматривается не совсем то, что я имею в виду.

Comment: @ixSci Да, вы правы. Действительно поведение не определено. В таком случае поддержка невыровненного доступа является чистым расширением, поддерживаемым данной реализацией.