# Что происходит когда мы явно приводим указатель?

Tags: c++, c

Когда мы приводим вещественный тип к целочисленному еще можно понять,там обрезаются лишние байты старших разрядов,но когда мы используем касты в указателях,например:

```
double a=4.55;
int *a=(int*)&a;
```

Зачем вообще нужно явное приведение в указателях?Если у нас известен базовый тип указателя,и неужели к нему нельзя приводить в выражениях?

И что происходит в памяти или с указателем когда мы явно приводим тип?

Comment: В первую очередь любой указатель это переменная, просто хранящая число, задающее адрес в памяти. Во вторую он *неявно* (в том смысле, что эти сведения "знает" компилятор, но при исполнении кода они нигде не сохрааняются) определяет тип (представление в памяти как цепочки бит определенного размера) адресуемого объекта. Так вот, приведение типа указателя это ваш сигнал компилятору, что вы понимаете, что делаете и берете дальнейшую ответственность за согласованность кода на себя.

Answer (score 2):

Приведение указателя и адресная арифметика дают в Си широкие возможности по работе с памятью, чего нет во множестве других языков.

Когда мы работаем с указателями, мы имеем дело не с переменными, а с областями памяти.

```
double a=4.55;
int *a=(int*)&a;
```

здесь происходит назначение указателя int* на область памяти, заполненную переменной типа double. с точки зрения нового указателя эта область памяти заполнена переменной типа int, именно так и будет интерпретироваться содержимое double переменной при обращении к этому содержимому через новый указатель. Сама область памяти и данные не меняются, они лишь по-иному интерпретируются.

Answer (score 0):

Приведение типа `A` к типу `B` - это не обрезание лишних байтов, и не добавление новых. Приведение типа - это преобразование **значения** типа `A` к значению типа `B`.

Объекты разных типов `A` и `B` могут занимать различное количество байтов, но иметь одинаковое значение. Или же они могут занимать одинаковое количество байтов, иметь в точности идентичные битовые паттерны, но при этом иметь разные значения.

Если вам нужно преобразовать, например, некоторое *значение* типа `float` в значение типа `int` вы можете написать так:

```
float d = 1.0f;
int i = d;
cout << i << endl; //Вывод: 1
```

Для преобразования значения одного типа в значение другого типа вам не нужно заботиться о том, какими именно последовательностями бит кодируется число `1` в типах `float` и `int`. Компилятор берёт эту работу на себя.

Однако, ни что не мешает вам интерпретировать байты, составляющие некоторый объект, на своё усмотрение ([код](https://ideone.com/At1Nxd)):

```
float d = 1.0f;
int* pi = (int*)&d;
cout << *pi << endl; //Возможный вывод: 1065353216
```

Возможный вывод может показаться несколько неожиданным. Переменная `d` хранит число `1`, но если на байты, составляющие переменную `d` взглянуть как на объект типа `int`, то там окажется совсем не единица. Более того, возможный вывод может быть другим на другой платформе.

В этом и состоит опасность вольной интерпретации байтов, составляющих некоторый объект. Результат может быть совсем не тем, который ожидается, может меняться в зависимости от платформы. Поэтому указатели преобразовываются явно, чтобы сказать компилятору: "всё нормально, в данном конкретном случае я знаю, что делаю".

P.S. Строго говоря, указатель `pi` в примере выше разыменовывать нельзя, так как это явное нарушение [strict aliasing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503265/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-strict-aliasing).

Да и тип `float *` не следует бездумно приводить к типу `int *`, так как это чревато нарушением [требований по выравниванию типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/%d0%9e-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85).

Answer (score 0):

Указатель – это просто адрес куска памяти, в котором лежит код некого значения или некой последовательности операций, обычно интерпретируемый программой или самим процессором как то, что он кодирует, соответственно, при приведении указателя на несовместимый тип к указателю на целое получается указатель на целочисленный код или его часть, занимающую старшие адреса, интерпретация при этом отбрасывается. Как именно кодируется то, на что указывал указатель? Это зависит от фактического формата, а в случае операций – от таблицы опкодов. Приведя указатель к указателю на инт, Вы просто вытащите результат этого кодирования. И при

```
double x;
int y=(int)x;
```

Обрезаются не старшие, а младшие биты.